Why is Swagger-UI unable to see the version field in my OpenAPI specification?
I am trying to setup Swagger UI to display an OpenAPI specification provided by PostgREST. Unfortunately, I get the following error:

Unable to render this definition
The provided definition does not specify a valid version field.
Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.x.y (for example, openapi: 3.1.0).

However, the version field is present exactly as the error message demands. Output of curl localhost:3000:
{
   "swagger":"2.0",
   "info":{
      "description":"",
      "title":"standard public schema",
      "version":"12.0.2"
   },
   ...
}

I've set up both PostgREST and Swagger UI via this ansible playbook:
- name: Deploy PostgREST as a docker container
  hosts: "<host>"
  tasks:
    - name: Setup PostgREST container
      docker_container:
        name: postgrest-report
        state: started
        restart_policy: always
        restart: "true"
        image: postgrest/postgrest
        pull: true
        network_mode: host
        env:
          PGRST_DB_URI: postgres://report:<password>@localhost:5432/report
          PGRST_DB_SCHEMA: public
          PGRST_DB_ANON_ROLE: report #In production this role should not be the same as the one used for the connection
          PGRST_SERVER_PROXY_URI: "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
          PGRST_SERVER-CORS-ALLOWED-ORIGINS: "http://localhost:3000"
    - name: Setup Swagger-UI container
      docker_container:
        name: swagger-ui-report
        state: started
        restart_policy: always
        restart: "true"
        image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui:latest
        network_mode: host
        env:
          API_URL: "http://localhost:3000"

I've also checked that the OpenAPI json is valid via https://editor.swagger.io.
My best guess is that said specification is not actually being read by Swagger UI. However, I've found no way to display the source of the definition Swagger UI is unable to render.

You could try using a different swagger-ui version, e.g. swaggerapi/swagger-ui:v4.19.1
. Or check if the request is done correctly to PostgREST at http://localhost:3000/ by using your browser debugger, e.g. pressing F12 and going to the Network tab in Firefox.

As a side note, there's an error in an env, it should be: PGRST_SERVER_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS and it should include the SwaggerUI origin (http://localhost:8080 if I'm not mistaken).

I've tried using different swagger versions, to no avail. I also corrected the CORS allowed origins. I can't see any network requests from my browser to PostgREST, but I also would not have expected any. My understanding was that those come directly from the SwaggerUI container.

But I can see the last request that swagger-ui:latest does to get the API document... and it's to http://localhost:3000/. In fact, it gave me a "Failed to load API definition." with a "Possible cross-origin (CORS) issue?", when I assigned a wrong Allowed Origin (hinting that it comes from the browser). I think it may be related to the network or exposing ports and Swagger cannot access localhost:3000.
